# Converting date from one format to another causes exception

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I am getting a date in this format:

> Fri Feb 28 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020

I need to convert this date to format `yyyy-mm-dd`

To get this format conversion I am doing as follows:

```java
String date = dateClicked.toString();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");

Date testDate = null;

try {
    testDate = sdf.parse(date);
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
System.out.println(".....dia pulsado..."+newFormat);
```

I am getting following exception at line `String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);`

This is the exception message: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference`

I guess the error is here: `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");`

Comment: use this new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy");

Comment: @shahzainali, let me check it

Comment: @shahzainali, I am gettint the same exception

Comment: you want capital m `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: @Blundell, you are right too

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested at my side this code is working perfectly

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String date = "Fri Mar 28 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020";

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");

        Date testDate = null;
        try {
            testDate = sdf.parse(date);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
        System.out.println(".....dia pulsado..."+newFormat);

    }
}
```

here is log

```
I/System.out: .....dia pulsado...2020-03-28
```

Comment: You are right, the error was not on the convertion but at the string date.